# if $ 0 < a < b $ then $0 < b^{-1} < a^{-1}$ using field axioms

Tags: real-analysis

Now since  $a,b >0$ so we have their inverses also greater than zero. So its left to prove that  $b^{-1} < a^{-1}$.

Let $c=a^{-1}b^{-1}$. So $0 < c$. Also $a < b$ so we have $ac < bc$. So we have a $aa^{-1}b^{-1} < b a^{-1}b^{-1}$. so using commutativity and distributivity we see that $b^{-1} < a^{-1}$

Is this correct ? Thanks

Comment: If you are just using the field axioms, and no order axiom, how do you know an order relation exists?  There are many non-ordered fields.

Comment: ordered-field axioms?

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use real number axioms ?

Comment: i am using real field axioms

Comment: and the real field axioms ...are ordered.  Thanks for your regular show of effort, Freja!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are actually using the axioms of *ordered* fields, your proof is correct (assuming you've already proven that the inverse of a positive number is positive). However there's no need to introduce $c$ (and not even a need to use commutativity).

Here is a version not using commutativity:

Since $0<a<b$, and $a^{-1}>0$, we have $a^{-1}0 < a^{-1}a < a^{-1}b$, that is, $0 < 1 < a^{-1}b$. Since $b^{-1}>0$, this further implies $0b^{-1} < 1b^{-1} < a^{-1}bb^{-1}$, which simplifies to $0<b^{-1}<a^{-1}$

Here besides the order axioms, we implicitly used the definition of $1$ and of the inverse, associativity and the fact that $0x=0$ for all $x$, which itself needs only distributivity and the group structure of addition to prove.